# Android ListView setId for each row

Tags: android, listview, adapter

How to set id for each row in ListView when using custom adapter?

TFragment:

```
public static TArrayAdapter adapter;
adapter = new TArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.t_list_item_adapter, new ArrayList<TString>());
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

TArrayAdapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t_list_item_adapter, parent, false);

    THolder holder = new TransactionHolder();
    holder.account = items.get(position);
    holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    rowView.setTag(holder);
    setupItem(holder);
```

Comment: Have you tried `rowView.setId(int)`?

Comment: How are you getting the id once the list is built? What are you trying to do?